# non-conformable arrays in calculation of the regression model

Tags: r

YC is a matrix with dimension= 39*1
XC is a matrix with dimension= 39*700

First I define a function in the following by calculating out the coefficient by Multi linear regression because i tried to get the predicted y of loocv. The error is Error in a + b1 %*% xp : non-conformable arrays.

```
mlr<- function(y,x,xp){
  ybar<-mean(y)
  xbar<-apply(x,1,mean)
  xc<-scale(x,center = T, scale= FALSE)
  b<-solve(t(xc)%*%xc)%*%t(xc)%*%y
  b1<-t(b)
  a<-ybar-b%*%xbar
  xp<- matrix(nrow=2,ncol=1)
  yp_LOOCV<-a+b1%*%xp
  return(yp_LOOCV)
}
 RMSECV<- sqrt(sum((total$YC - yp_LOOCV)^2)/39)
```

Second part is to plug the function into the LOOCV loop to calculate the RMSE of the data. The reason why i didnt applied a package and use commend lm() is that i will use the loop repeatedly afterwards by applying the pca and PLR.Could please see what else i should modify to correct the error?

```
YC<-data.frame(YC)
XPred<-cbind(total$X1590,total$X1724)
n <- 0
yp_LOOCV <- as.vector(0)
#Running the LOOCV iteratively ('for loop').
for (i in 1 : 39)
{n <- 1 + n 
YC1 <-YC[-n,]
XC1<-XPred[-n,]
Yout<-YC[n]
Xout<-XPreduced[n]
yp_LOOCV<-mlr(YC1,XC1,Xout)
}
```

Comment: the model I want use to use is YC~X1590+X1724

Comment: Use `debug(mlr)` (then run the `mlr` function) to step through `mlr` until `b1` and `xp` are in scope. Printing them will show that matrix multiplication between these two objects is undefined due to their dimensions - i.e. they are non-conformable with respect to matrix multiplication. Maybe you accidentally transposed one somewhere, and didn't take this in to account when continuing?

Comment: how to type the code?                                                               debug(mlr)
> mlr<- function(y,x,xp){
+   ybar<-mean(y)
+   xbar<-apply(x,1,mean)
+   xc<-scale(x,center= TRUE, scale= FALSE)
+   b<-solve(t(xc)%*%xc)%*%t(xc)%*%y
+   b1<-t(b)
+   a<-ybar-b%*%xbar
+   xp<- matrix(nrow=2,ncol=1)
+   yp_LOOCV<-a+b1%*%xp
+   return(yp_LOOCV)
+ }   but nothing show up

Comment: Call `debug(mlr)` after defining the function. Now try running the function to step in to it. `undebug(mlr)` undoes the `debug` flag.

Comment: I figure out why i got that error, but i still did not get the right answer of RMSECV<- sqrt(sum((YC - yp_LOOCV)^2)/39). the answer of it is NA. and i find that the dimension of RMSECV is 2*39 . However, it should be a number. Do u know how can i modify it ?

Comment: You never actually call i in your loop? I think you mixed up n and I